# Ember Edit Template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember app which has a `profiles` route to display a title and a description of a particular item from the database. I want to create an `edit` page for that data, as in CRUD in ember. I implemented an `edit` route under the `profiles` resource route.

The `index` template works fine, it successfully populates the data from the database and the results show in the template. However, as soon as I declare a controller for that route and add an action to that controller the template breaks.

Here is the app.js code for the app.

```
App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
title: DS.attr('string'),
description: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Router.map(function(){
this.resource("about", function(){
    this.route("create", {path: '/create'});
});
this.resource('profiles', {path: '/profiles/:profiles_id'}, function(){
    this.route('edit');
});
this.resource('login');
this.resource("logout");
});

App.ProfilesController = Ember.Controller.extend();

App.ProfilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(params) {
    NProgress.start();
    var data = App.Profile.find(params.profiles_id);
    data.then(function(){
      NProgress.done();
    });
    return data;
}
});
```

The Html Code for profiles:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="profiles">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p>
    {{description}}
  </p>
  <form {{action edit on="submit"}}>
    {{input value=title type="text" placeholder="Title"}}
    {{textarea value=description}}
    {{input class="button" type="submit" value="Edit"}}
  </form>
</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

At this point everything works fine. but as soon as i add edit action to ProfileController, when i load the page in the browser only the form with no data is shown. what went wrong?

when i add this code to the ProfilesController onyl the form with no data is shown:

```
App.ProfilesController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    edit: function(){
        var self =this, data = this.getProperties('title', 'description');
        self.set('errorMessage', null);
        self.set('successMsg', null);
        Ember.$.put('profiles', data, function(){
            NProgress.start();
        }).then(function(response){
            NProgress.done();
            if(response.success){

            }else {
                self.set('errorMessage', response.message);
                console.log(response.message);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I want to create an action when the form is submitted, the edit action get triggered and do the put on the server, i have php laravel 4 backend at the server to handle the request RESTfully.

I tried to implement the above code under edit template as in profiles/edit template but i couldn't make it work, so i pasted the code in index template of profiles.

Ember displays this log on console

> generated -> route:profiles.index Object {fullName: "route:profiles.index"} ember-1.0.0.js:356
>
> Rendering application with default view <(subclass of
>   Ember.View):ember330> Object {fullName: "view:application"}
>   ember-1.0.0.js:356
>
> Rendering profiles with default view 
>   Object {fullName: "view:profiles"} ember-1.0.0.js:356
>
> generated -> controller:profiles.index Object {fullName:
>   "controller:profiles.index"} ember-1.0.0.js:356
>
> Could not find "profiles.index" template or view. Nothing will be
>   rendered Object  {fullName: "template:profiles.index"}
>   ember-1.0.0.js:356
>
> generated -> route:index Object {fullName: "route:index"}
>   ember-1.0.0.js:356
>
> generated -> route:about.index Object {fullName: "route:about.index"}
>   ember-1.0.0.js:356

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. For putting it inside profiles/edit template, you would need a profiles.hbs template which has {{outlet}} defined. That way edit template will get shown. Also, profiles.hbs should be outside of profiles directory. and profiles directory should contain index and edit templates.
2. I think it should be an ArrayController instead of just Controller.

I think once  you change according to point 1, it should work properly. Give it a try.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer, but upto now i havent been using hbs files and i dont know how to use them with laravel at backend , using above code can you please describe me little further, controller and hbs corrections that you are suggesting ?

Comment: You don't have to use hbs files. Basically profiles data-template-name should have {{outlet}} and you would have 2 other data-template-names with profiles/index and profiles/edit. You can keep all of them in a single file also.